# How to not display a checkbox if the value is equal to a variable from an array

Tags: jquery, laravel

I would like to not display the checkbox that has the value equal to zero. Is there any way of using Jquery(or any other way that I have not tagged) to achieve this?

Blade syntax below:

```
@foreach ($displays as $display)
   <div class="divclass">
      <input name="subject{{$display->subject}}" id="list" type="checkbox" value="{{$display->id}}">{{$display->name}}
   </div>
@endforeach
```

One of the `{{$display->id}}` is zero and so how could I ensure that the div does not get displayed?

Comment: what about if statement inside foreach?

Comment: inside your `@foreach` put `@if ($display->id != 0)`

Comment: ahh I didnt know you could do that. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach ($displays as $display)
   if($display->id != 0)
   {
    <div>
      <input name="subject{{$display->subject}}" id="list" type="checkbox" value="{{$display->id}}">{{$display->name}}
    </div>
   }
@endforeach
```

you can use the the value is not equal to 0 the only enter into the div tag otherwise dont enter then it will not display the check box.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
@foreach ($displays as $display)
 @if ($display->id != 0)
   <div class="divclass"><input name="subject{{$display->subject}}" id="list" type="checkbox" value="{{$display->id}}">{{$display->name}}</div>
 @endif
@endforeach
```